# Paypal Checkout Button is not passing custom filed to IPN message

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout

I'm updating the PayPal system on my website, replacing older PayPal buttons with newer PayPal Checkout, and I have problems while trying to pass the custom field from the button script to the IPN message that I use to update my database with customer's payments: I receive the IPN message with all the rights $_POST fields/values, except for the $_POST['custom'] field that always remains empty. I'm using sandbox merchant and customer accounts, this is my button code:

```
<script src='https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxx&currency=EUR' data-sdk-integration-source='button-factory'></script>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        label: 'pay',
        tagline: true
    },
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '1'
                },
                custom: '35627187'
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with `custom_id`, as documented in the [Checkout Orders API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit) for a purchase_unit

`custom` will be ignored

Comment: Wonderful! I guess I wouldn't be able to find it by myself inside that long long reference page.. I looked for it on google a lot, with no luck. Than you so much!

Comment: Ah, well Cmd/Ctrl+F helps